# Extend Date in my Dataframe

Tags: r

My data looks like the following

```
Date          Value
2/11/2016     20.0
2/18/2016     21.0
2/25/2016     18.3
3/4/2016      19.1
3/11/2016     26.3
3/18/2016     21.1
  NA          26.2
  NA          18.6
  NA          17.9
```

I want to add date in place of "NA". SO the new data looks like

```
Date          Value
2/11/2016     20.0
2/18/2016     21.0
2/25/2016     18.3
3/4/2016      19.1
3/11/2016     26.3
3/18/2016     21.1
3/25/2016     26.2
1/4/2016     18.6
8/4/2016       17.9
```

Note that addition of date is 7 increment of the previous date. Can anyone please help me how to extend the date?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most software, R stores dates as numeric values under the hood. Assuming this is a one-off problem and your data are stored as numeric, you could do it with a little `for` loop. If they're currently character variables, coerce to date using `as.Date()` first.

```
for(i in 7:9){
  df$Date[i] <- df$Date[i-1]+7
}
```

Though I'm sure there are other wizards here who have a vectorized solution....

Comment: `df$Date[7:9] <- df$Date[6] + (1:3)*7` should do.